# Is correctness implied by an optimality proof?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, greedy-algorithms, correctness-proof

New to proofs (in the context of analysis of algorithms).

I'm wondering, if I were to prove a greedy algorithm is the optimal solution, does this imply its correctness as well? (partial correctness + termination).

I'm trying to understand how The Job Sequencing Problem is correct but can only find proofs for its optimality. How can we be sure this algorithm is correct?

EDIT: I have found an excellent resource that uses a proof of optimality to show (I think) partial correctness as well. It is here but for the life of me I cannot understand it. A layman's explanation would be amazing!

Comment: Termination is usually obvious for greedy algorithms.

Comment: And optimality is the definition of correctness in optimization-type problems

Comment: Maybe edit your post to include a reference to your resource so we can have a look at it?